# Visual code key shortcut navigate search sidebar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> opens up the search all files sidebar in Visual Studio Code. But what are the shortcuts for navigating the search result? You can use the arrows in file explorer to navigate files in the but not for search results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an unbound command `search.action.focusSearchList` which will focus the search list and then the arrow keys work.

So set it to your chosen keybinding (in keybindings.json) like so:

```
{
  "key": "alt+m",
  "command": "search.action.focusSearchList"
},
```

or just click in the search list (changing focus to it) and then arrows work.

You could also try <kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> which will open in a preview editor the next/previous search result.

Comment: I realized that you can press tab 5 times until the searchlist gets focus and then use the arrows :)