# In vscode, how do I jump to the results of "find in files" without using the mouse

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In vscode, when searching text in all files with `ctrl + shift + f`, is there a fast way to cycle through the found results? Currently I press `ctrl + arrow down` multiple times to navigate to the result list, but that still feels clumsy compared to fzf in Vim.

Comment: You want either https://stackoverflow.com/a/59681307/836330 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/59681307/836330.

Comment: The answer to the linked question definitely is an improvement. I'd still hope that there's a possibility to directly jump to the next/previous search result with just a single key combination though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a sequence of commands to go to the next or prev search when you are in the editor.

Use extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command)

Add this to `keybindings.json`

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+f3",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { 
        "sequence": [
            "search.action.focusSearchList",
            "list.focusDown",
            "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "key": "shift+ctrl+alt+f3",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { 
        "sequence": [
            "search.action.focusSearchList",
            "list.focusUp",
            "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup"
        ]
    }
}
```

If you are currently at the last or first hit for a file you have to use the key combi a second time.

**Edit** : modified the Up/Down command to use (`list` instead of `cursor`)

---

Just found out ([Mark made a question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75808371/9938317)) that VSC now (v1.77 insiders) has a build in command to run a sequence of commands. In certain situations you can do without `multi-command`. (Some users are not allowed to install extensions at work)

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+f3",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": { 
        "commands": [
            "search.action.focusSearchList",
            "list.focusDown",
            "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup"
        ]
    }
},
{
    "key": "shift+ctrl+alt+f3",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": { 
        "commands": [
            "search.action.focusSearchList",
            "list.focusUp",
            "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Edit**

If you modify an item text in the editor and it no longer matches the searched text you have to use a different method because the list has put the focus on the next item: use `Ctrl+0` and `Enter`

**Edit**

Replaced `workbench.action.focusSideBar` with `search.action.focusSearchList`

VSC will select the search bar if it is not visible.

Comment: This would be a nice solution - unfortunately doesn't work on my machine. What this does for me is to move the cursor one line down or up. It seems the `cursorDown`/`cursorUp` is somehow executed in the editor window instead of in the sidebar.

Comment: @jan I tried and had the same behavior. I need to use a different command for cursor movement, try the modified bindings

Comment: Thanks! I needed to replace `workbench.action.focusSideBar` with `search.action.focusSearchList` for it to work reliably.

Comment: Good to hear that this will soon work without any plugin!

Comment: @jan If the focus is on the search list, with `Ctrl+Down` then `workbench.action.focusSideBar` works, I did not know of the command `search.action.focusSearchList`

Answer (score 1):

For me, when focused in the Search all Files box, hitting F4 cycles through the results, opening it in the editor and placing the cursor at the result. VSCode version 1.84.2.