# How can I make a VS Code keybinding only apply when a specific View is visible/focused?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I'm coming from other IDEs in which when you globally search for some content across your project (in Visual studio code it's done by pressing CMD+SHIT+F) and then want to move between the founded items, you just press down/up and start moving between them.

I was looking to get this kind of behavior in Visual Studio Code, I found out there's a command for that that is describerd here: [In vscode, how do I jump to the results of "find in files" without using the mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75746413/in-vscode-how-do-i-jump-to-the-results-of-find-in-files-without-using-the-mou)

But when I was doing the following in`keybinds.json`:

```
[
  {
    "key": "down",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": { 
        "commands": [
            "search.action.focusSearchList",
            "list.focusDown",
            "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup"
        ]
    }
  },
  {
      "key": "up",
      "command": "runCommands",
      "args": { 
          "commands": [
              "search.action.focusSearchList",
              "list.focusUp",
              "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup"
          ]
      }
  }
]
```

It just messed up, so when I'm coding and want to move line down by pressing the down key, it applies the sequence commands in the `keybinds.json`

Is there a way to achieve my goal? So for instance only to apply the above commands when I'm focused on the search pane?

Comment: you can see if there is a context var that signals the search pane focus and put that in a `when` property, or add a modifier `Shift/Alt/Ctrl`

Answer (score 0):

See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#visible-view-container-when-clause-context. You can check which viewlet is visible with the `activeViewlet` context key, and check if the sidebar is focused with the `sideBarFocus` context key.

You want to add a when clause like `"sideBarFocus && activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.search'"`. If you also want to cover cases where the Search View is moved into the Panel area or the Secondary/Auxiliary sidebar, then do `"sideBarFocus && (activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.search' || activePanel == 'workbench.view.search' || activeAuxiliary == 'workbench.view.search')"`.

For visiblility, see also [the list of Global UI context keys](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#available-context-keys)

Or, for the focused view, see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#visiblefocused-view-when-clause-context. Use the `view.${viewId}.visible` context key. Not all views seem to be supported here though.